# MySQL count(col) that returns null

Tags: mysql, count

I have 3 tables :

- Teams (id_team, name, id_season)
- Teams_Stats (id_stats, id_game, id_team, victory, defeat)
- Seasons (id_season, name, nbr_teams)

I'm trying to pull out the number of victories for each team for a specific season (2015 in this case).

That's what I have so far, but it returns 0 for all the teams.

my SQL syntax :

```
SELECT T.name, count(a.victory) as Wins
FROM Teams T, Seasons S
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT TS.id_team, TS.victory FROM Teams_Stats TS WHERE TS.victory = 1) a
  ON a.id_team = 'T.id_team'
WHERE T.id_season = S.id_season AND S.name = '2015'
GROUP BY T.nom 
ORDER BY T.nom
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks :)

Comment: should the GROUP BY & ORDER BY read T.name

Comment: That was a typo ....  my bad.  Original statement and database are in french.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your query a bit like

```
SELECT T.name, count(TS.victory) as Wins
FROM Teams T
JOIN Seasons S ON T.id_season = S.id_season AND S.name = '2015'
LEFT JOIN Teams_Stats TS ON TS.id_team = T.id_team AND TS.victory = 1
GROUP BY T.name 
ORDER BY T.name
```

Comment: That was quick ! It works perfectly! You are a life saver :) Thanks !